# sys/types.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c, linux, module, include, kernel

I am trying to compile module but get this error.

```
fatal error: sys/types.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

Here is my module file headers

```
#include <linux/init.h>           // Macros used to mark up functions e.g. __init __exit
#include <linux/module.h>         // Core header for loading LKMs into the kernel
#include <linux/device.h>         // Header to support the kernel Driver Model
#include <linux/kernel.h>         // Contains types, macros, functions for the kernel
#include <linux/fs.h>             // Header for the Linux file system support
#include <asm/uaccess.h>          // Required for the copy to user function
#include <sys/types.h>
```

And my `Makefile`

```
obj-m = test.o

all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules
clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

I have tried to search for this file

```
 find /usr/include -name types.h
```

Here are results

```
/usr/include/sys/types.h
/usr/include/libr/sdb/types.h
/usr/include/rpc/types.h
/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/sys/types.h
/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/asm/types.h
/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/bits/types.h
/usr/include/linux/iio/types.h
/usr/include/linux/types.h
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/types.h
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/asm/types.h
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/types.h
/usr/include/asm-generic/types.h
/usr/include/c++/5/parallel/types.h
```

I tried to set it as `#include "/usr/include/sys/types.h"`

but got following error

```
/usr/include/sys/types.h:25:22: fatal error: features.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

I am using `Kali Linux(Debian)` AMD64 platform

```
Linux kali 4.5.0-kali1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.5.5-1kali1 (2016-06-06) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

What is wrong ? Thanks

**SOLVED**

Sorry this was my fault, I made a typo in type and tried to include `sys/types.h` file, but it was not required at all all types are declared in `/usr/src/linux-headers-4.5.0-kali1-common/include/linux/types.h` in my case. Thanks everyone.

Comment: Just add an answer to your own question instead of updating your question as "***SOLVED***". You also can accept your own answer then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry this was my fault, I made a typo in type and tried to include sys/types.h file, but it was not required at all all types are declared in /usr/src/linux-headers-4.5.0-kali1-common/include/linux/types.h in my case. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 37):

I had a similar error with Linux Mint

> fatal error: sys/types.h: No such file or directory

Fixed this problem with:

```
sudo apt install libc6-dev
```

Comment: Thanks, this also fixed the install for Perl `Net::AMQP::RabbitMQ` module.

Comment: Thank you very much for an EC2 ubuntu instance this fix was perfect to be able to install `mod-wsgi`

Answer (score 4):

I'd suggest looking to see if `gcc` is looking for header files in the directory where your file is located with the command:

```
`gcc -print-prog-name=cc1` -v      # for c
```

Comment: Thanks for answer   `#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/include-fixed
 /usr/include
`

Comment: Is that your entire `makefile`?

Comment: Yes this is entire file

Comment: Based on your OP it looks like once you included the entire path it was able to find `types.h`. Try doing a `find` for your file `features.h` now and see where that is. You may have to include the absolute directory for that as well.

Comment: @ketazafor It shouldn't be necessary to provide absolute paths, or any paths at all ... every instance of gcc should know the location of the headers for that instance. It sounds like a configuration error.

Comment: I have tried a lot, install `gcc-multilib` but still the same problem. I have no idea what to do ((

Comment: cc1plus should be used instead of cc1 for g++

Answer (score 3):

You can fix this problem with:

```
sudo apt-get install libc6-dev-i386
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just add the `types` header file to your sources, download from [here](http://unix.superglobalmegacorp.com/Net2/newsrc/sys/types.h.html).

Comment: What do you mean just add this file ? As you can see I have already tried to include it, furthermore there is no `ssize_t` defined provided by you file.

Comment: Download the file and add it to your project directory and then try to  include it, and regarding to ssize_t just add the line:typedef unsigned int ssize_t;